# weird border placement

Tags: html, css

I have found some weird CSS bug.

I have a `<div>` container with some text and a Font-Awesome icon inside. The `<div>` container is styled so that it has a small border. The weird thing is  that the border seems to *"think"* that the `<div>` is only half the height of what it actually is.

This occurs only in Chrome mobile (Android) but not in Chrome desktop (not tested in safari and co...)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    Lade Daten... <li class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></li>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px)
{
    .sidebar {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 20px;
    }
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    width: 335px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: rgb(60,60,60);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', Arial;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). FYI, `li` should be used inside of a `ul`, `ol` or `menu`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/z9u4uL0h/. In your case I'd highly recommend remote debugging your website, here's a great tutorial on remote debugging Android devices: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Let me see.....  Maybe the `margin: 0 20px;` has something to do with it or maybe `width: auto;`.  Maybe you could try `position: absolute;`.  I don't know.  Did any of these suggestions work for you?

Comment: You have to show the HTML code of the elements around that element, and their CSS, otherwise it's not possible to help you. BTW, if the order of the CSS rules is really as you posted it, the position and width of  `.sidebar` defined in the media query will be overwritten by the rule following after it.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `height: (px you want it)` in your `@media query`

Comment: This is a poor solution. Every time the content changes you have to manually change the `height` value. There's nothing, as of now, that says that this would be the only way to rectify the problem. There's also a high likely hood that this will be fixed with something more flexible, i.e. clearing floats.